# Java have a int value using setText

Tags: java, jtextfield

I'm trying to set an int value using jTextField and the setText method. But of course setText wants a String. How do I get round this? I'll give you a snippet of the code:

```
    private void setAllTextFields(FilmSystem e){
    getFilmNameTF().setText(e.getFilmName());
    lectureTF.setText(e.getLecture());
    ageTF.setText(e.getAge());
    priceTF.setText(e.getTicketCost());
    seatsTF.setText(e.getNoOfSeats());
```

seatsTF is a jTextField and getNoOfSeats is a method in another class that returns a int value.

Thanks again for answering this question. Now how would I go about getting the value of the int to do something to do?

```
        public void buyTicket() {
    String newFilmName = filmNameTF.getText();
    String newLecture = lectureTF.getText();
    String newAge = ageTF.getText();
    String newPrice = priceTF.getText(); 
    int newSeats = seatsTF.
```

As you can see the code, the String values I can get easy with getText. I can then print them out or whatever with them. How can I do this with the seats int? Thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

`String#valueOf` convert your `int` to `String`.

`String.valueOf(e.getAge());` will return the `string` representation of the `int` argument.

```
seatsTF.setText(String.valueOf(e.Age()));
...
```

Comment: I don't want to because I want to do maths on the int value later.

Comment: your actual int value will not be changed.

Answer (score 1):

USe

```
seatsTF.setText(""+e.getNoOfSeats());
```

OR

```
seatsTF.setText(String.valueOf(e.getNoOfSeats()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Normal ways would be

```
seatsTF.setText(Integer.toString(e.getNoOfSeats()));
```

or

```
seatsTF.setText(String.valueOf(e.getNoOfSeats()));
```

but, this can be achieved with a concatenation like this:

```
seatsTF.setText("" + e.getNoOfSeats());
```

Comment: I used the String.valueOf solution and it worked fine. Well it didn't like it when it pasted it in but it asked me to change it to an italics. I never understood that. Anyway thanks for the quick replies guys.

Comment: I've edited my original post, wondered if you could help with my another problem.

Comment: It is not a big problem buddy. You can just do int newSeats = Integer.parseInt(seatsTF.getText());

Answer (score 0):

Assuming age field is of type int, you could try something like:

```
        ageTF.setText( Integer.toString(e.getAge()) );
```

Comment: Age is a String, I don't need to do anything to age but print it out so I left it as a String. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Setting an `int` converting it to a `String` not a big deal. Displaying a value is a problem. To take care of how the value is displayed properly in the textfield you may use a [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) to format the numeric value. But may be the number is `locale` specific then you need [`NumberFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) instance

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(locale);
nf.setMaximumIntegerDigits(12);
nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(0);
nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(0);
String s = nf.format(e.getNoOfSeats());
seatsTF.setText(s);
```

You may also need to read the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html) on how to use the `DecimalFormat`.

Answer (score 0):

To convert Integer Value to String  you should

```
MedicineTM medicine=tblmedicine.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

    txtmedicine.setText(medicine.getMID());
    txtDescription.setText(medicine.getDescription());
    txtQty.setText(String.valueOf(medicine.getQty()));  // this is what i did
    cmbApproval.setValue(medicine.getApproval());
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you should write the code as

seatsTF.setText(e.getNoOfSeats().toString());

Comment: You can't call methods on an `int`.